# How to subscribe youtube channel in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube, youtube-api

I have one custom `UIButton`. that button functionality is subscribing one default `Youtube` channel. is this possible to subscribe channel in my apps. please share some code or guide link.

Comment: Have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186151/ios-google-api-youtube-subscribe-to-a-channel). Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the YouTube API into your Objective-C application in order to do this.

**Step 1**

Since you want to enable the user to subscribe to a channel, you have to use `OAuth 2.0` to allow the user to securely login to their YouTube account. The `OAuth 2.0` is pretty simple to implement. Essentially it consists of the app opening up a Google login web page, getting the user to login/approve app access and then getting a callback string which contains a special code. You then use this code in a `POST` request to verify/obtain the user `refresh/access tokens` (a long string which represents a logged in user).

**Step 2**

Store the access token string securely in Keychain, don't user `NSUserDefaults`! Use the `FDKeychain` wrapper class to easily save/load the user access token to the OS keychain. You can access this wrapper class on Github: https://github.com/reidmain/FDKeychain

**Step 3**

Now you need to search through the Google (YouTube) developer API documentation, in order to find out how to subscribe to a channel. In fact I've found it: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert

But basically it consists of you making a `POST` request to this API link: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions

In the request you simply include the ID of the channel you wish to subscribe to and the access token of the user. Once the request has been made, you will receive a request response. Check the response for any error codes/etc.... If all went well, then the user has been successfully subscribed to the channel, otherwise parse the error code/description and alert the user.

**Note**

Access tokens don't last forever, they need to be refreshed from time to time. In order to refresh an access token, you need to make a `POST` request with your access token and refresh token to the Google API, learn more here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

The response of the above request, will return a new access token.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert Actually objective c are not here

Comment: @iosdeveloperweb.wordpress.com The code samples they have there are for their own custom SDKs. For iOS/macOS you have two choices, use the Google SDK (not recommended as its rubbish), or just create your network request using ```NSURLSession``` (which is much simple). If you read that page, you'll see that it tells you the URL to use and the parameters you need to pass, in order to make the request. It's pretty simple.